# Forcing Xcode to compile a file every time?

Tags: c++, xcode, compilation, xcode8

My about box shows the compile time for debugging purposes, but for some reason, I can't get Xcode to ALWAYS recompile a file which stores the compile time. I've tried using `touch` but it's not working.

In my target's pre-build script, I have this:

```
/usr/bin/touch -c ../../Source/CompileTime.h
```

And that file looks like this:

```
class CompileTime
{
public:
    CompileTime(){}
    String getCompileTime()
    {
        String bTime (__TIME__);
        String bDate (__DATE__);
        String buildDate = bTime + " - " + bDate;
        return buildDate;
    }
};
```

My hope is that it ALWAYS recompiles that file and so every build has a new time. But for some reason, sometimes it does not recompile it for whatever reason and I see the same time and date in the about window as before.

Is there some sort of caching going on? How can I correct this?

Comment: what is the command you are using?

Comment: /usr/bin/touch -c ../../Source/CompileTime.h

Comment: No to compile. The first thing you need to do is to put this on a cpp file, and to use the clean command to compile. If you have a script, you can also delete the resulting object file for this cpp, that way it will never exist.

Comment: I can definitely put that code in a cpp file, but where is the object file? Why wouldn't a touch of the header file force it? I was hoping to keep it simple.

Comment: touching the header no, the cpp might work.

Comment: Actually, I had it that way at first. Was just as unreliable.

Comment: what about 'xcodebuild -alltargets clean'? what is is your compile command?